# Cannot build Android Project after creating new Variant

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

From the Android Studio I created a new build variant for an existing android project. I have very little knowledge of Android development in general and from what im understanding I also created a directory under app but now i also need the google-service.json as Im getting the following error:

Execution failed for task ':app:processMyVariantDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

How do I generate this file. tried to copy it from the other variants but of course it is not that simple. looks like something that needs to be generated.

Anyone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: your firebase json file is missing, add that google-services.json.